# Add Accounting Radius in the RAS (VPN) Configuration

Tags: vpn, powershell, script, radius, accounting

I'm trying to create a powershell script for configuring a specific VPN remote access server in a Windows Server 2012-R2, the following command works fine but how can i configure accounting radius too?

```
Install-RemoteAccess -PassThru -VpnType VPN -MsgAuthenticator Enabled -RadiusPort 1645 -RadiusScore 30 -RadiusServer 127.0.0.1 -RadiusTimeout 10 -SharedSecret "password" -IPAddressRange "10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.254"
```

Cause i tried `Set-RemoteAccessRadius` or `Add-RemoteAccessRadius` but i get errors in the both commands! for example:

> A RADIUS server cannot be added because RADIUS accounting is not
>   enabled.
>
> The RADIUS server on localhost is not configured for the specified
>   purpose. Settings were not applied.

I don't know how to enable RADIUS accounting first so i can add my RADIUS accounting!

Comment: A quick look did you use the `-AccountingOnOffMsg` argument when using the `Set-RemoteAccessRadius` cmdlet... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918417(v=wps.630).aspx and http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/you-need-to-ensure-that-all-of-the-vpn-connections-to-server1-are-logged-to-the-radius-server-on-server2-3/ may be of use?

Comment: @BigChris Yes i did, and i get this error : `The RADIUS server on localhost is not configured for the specified purpose. Settings were not applied.`

Comment: What string do you have for the `Set-RemoteAccessRadius`? I wonder if it's if you're missing the `-Purpose` argument - can't say until we have the string :)

Comment: @BigChris `Set-RemoteAccessRadius -ServerName 127.0.0.1 -Purpose Accounting -Timeout 10 -Port 1646 -SharedSecret "password" -PassThru -AccountingOnOffMsg Enabled`

Comment: And when i use `Add-RemoteAccessRadius -ServerName 127.0.0.1 -Purpose Accounting -Timeout 10 -Port 1646 -SharedSecret "password" -PassThru -AccountingOnOffMsg Enabled` i get this error : `A RADIUS server cannot be added because RADIUS accounting is not enabled.`

Comment: Would the `Set-RemoteAccessAccounting` cmdlet be of use? https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/remoteaccess/set-remoteaccessaccounting

Comment: @BigChris Yes it worked .. Please answer so i could mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Set-RemoteAccessAccounting` cmdlet in PowerShell seems to have resolved the user's problem.